# internal CSS styling in React at the top of code

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to style a component in my React application, but I do not want to create an external stylesheet because it's a small project. How can I style this image component without using an external stylesheet?

```
return (
  <div>
    <Image>
      <div>
        <img src='./resources/image.png alt='image'>
      </div>
    </Image>
  </div>
);
```

I've found resources online for using inline styling on a specific element, but I want to make my code clean by putting it at the top of the component like using a style tag at the top of an HTML file. I haven't been able to find anything that resembles this in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal CSS styling in JSX is very similar to how it's done in HTML. The only difference is that you need to declare the style names as variables because they are treated like JS objects. With this in mind, you also need to end each property with a comma instead of a semicolon, and the last property should have no punctuation at the end. Using this approach, you should also use `style={}` instead of `className={}`. You can read more about JSX styling [here](https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822).

```
const myStyle = {
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px',
    border: '2px solid black'
}

const Image = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <img style={myStyle} src='./resources/image.png alt='image'>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For inline styles you can define a style object, either at the top of the file, or in your render method, and then refer to it:

```
var myStyle = { margin: 10 }

return (
  <div>
    <Image>
      <div>
        <img style={myStyle} src='./resources/image.png alt='image'>
      </div>
    </Image>
  </div>
)
```

More info in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: Waoh, I didn't even think of this. Love how you kept it "just javascript"-y :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
const Image = styled.div`
      background: #1d9ac2;

      img {
          border: 1px solid red;
      }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for this, and a big debate about which one is "the best".
I don't know which one is the best, but I can tell you which one I use:

Styled components (https://www.styled-components.com/)

With this, you would define an object like this

```
let styled = require('styled-components');
// Or for fancy people
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Image = styled.div`
  background-color: red;

  /* You can even put classes or selectors in here that will match the sub-components */
  .some_class_used_inside { color: black; }
  img { width: 100px }
`
```

and use it like this

```
return (
  <div>
    <Image> {/* This will be the `<div>` with `background-color: red` */}
      <div className="some_class_used_inside"> {/* This will now have `color: black` applied */
        <img src='./resources/image.png alt='image'> {/* This will have `width: 100px` applied to it */}
      </div>
    </Image>
  </div>
);
```

Ofcourse, there are many other libraries to do it, and everyone will have to find their own favorite I guess :)